# Spring Security - CSRF - How to reset CSRF token and log a potential CSRF attack (OWASP recommendation)

Tags: security, spring-security, csrf, csrf-protection, owasp

We are using Spring Security framework in our application, especially to prevent it against CSRF attacks.

In the [OWASP document about CSRF attacks prevention cheat sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet), they talk about the Synchronizer Token Pattern. So, when a wrong CSRF token is provided, they recommend to:

1. Abort the request
2. Reset the CSRF token
3. Log the event as a potential CSRF attack in progress

I did a test, providing a wrong CSRF and get the following results :

1. The request is abort and the response's status is set to 403 (= Forbiden)
2. The **token is not reset**
3. A **simple DEBUG log** is done by the Spring CSRFFilter : "Invalid CSRF token found for *REQUESTED_URL*"

So, my question are:

- Q1: Is it possible to **ask Spring Security to reset the CSRF token?**
- Q2:  Is it possible to **ask Spring Security to log a WARN message instead of a DEBUG message about a potential CSRF attack in progress?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are not alone. I am still figure out how to reset the token.

To answer your q2, you can specify a custom AccessDeniedHandler, which  allows you to process the InvalidCsrfTokenException in the way you like. The details you can find [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html#csrf-configure).